# Jaeger instrumentation for Spring Cloud RxJava

Tags: java, spring, maven, jaeger

I'm trying to instrument a Spring Cloud RxJava sample app with OpenTracing, and for some reason I'm failing!

I have a couple of other SpringCloud apps, like Hystrix, JDBC and JMS working fine with the tracing being reported to Jeager by just adding the maven dependency to it.

For RxJava, on the other hand, I can't figure it out why I'm not able to follow the same approach...

When I leave the App without a `Tracer @Bean`, I don't get anything in Jaeger and I get this message:

```
Tracer bean is not configured! Switching to NoopTracer
```

All the other SpringCloud apps are working without the `Tracer @Bean`, so I was expecting the same behavior for the RxJava...

The worst part is that whenever I add the `Tracer @Bean`, the bean is initialized, but still no data is sent to Jaeger...
Not sure if it is related to this message:

```
Bean 'tracer' of type [io.jaegertracing.Tracer] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Do I need to set anything in the `application.properties`?

I'm posting below my `pom.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.springcloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>rxjava</name>
    <description>RxJava Spring Cloud</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR6</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentracing-spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
            <version>0.5.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentracing-spring-cloud-starter-jaeger</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.reactivex</groupId>
            <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentracing</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentracing-util</artifactId>
            <version>0.32.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentracing</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentracing-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.32.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Sample app committed here: https://github.com/julianocosta89/rxjava-jeager

Comment: Did you try `opentracing.spring.cloud.rxjava.enabled=true` to enable `Rxjava` tracing?

Comment: Yep... Also no success

Answer (score 0):

**Update**:

I got the same exception (`Tracer bean is not configured!..`) when I use your version of spring cloud jaeger dependencies. This is irrespective of the `RxJava` package.

I think you can directly use `opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter` which is a combination of `opentracing-spring-cloud-starter` and `opentracing-spring-jaeger-starter`. Read [this details](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-jaeger/blob/master/README.md) for java spring jaeger.

> The opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter starter is convenience
> starter that includes both opentracing-spring-jaeger-starter and
> opentracing-spring-cloud-starter This means that by including it, all
> parts of the Spring Cloud stack supported by Opentracing will be
> instrumented

**Note**:

Maybe RxJava tracing won't work without registering the tracer using the decorators provided by [opentracing-contrib](https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-rxjava/blob/master/README.md). Please see the working app [here](https://github.com/akashsolanki/rxjava-jeager).

I have followed [this spring guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/reactive-rest-service/) for Reactive Restful webservice and `jaeger` worked with below `pom.xml` without any `Tracer bean` -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.spring.opentrace</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaeger</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jaeger</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR6</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
          <artifactId>opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
          <groupId>io.reactivex</groupId>
          <artifactId>rxjava</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Hello @Akash, the example that you have shared actually doesn't use the RX package. I already have an app with reactor working, I'm looking for a solution using RxJava.

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought you're trying to trace Reactive webservice. May I know what exactly are you trying to trace in `RxJava`?

Comment: I'm basically testing the Jaeger capabilities, so I have rx.Observable, rx.Subscriber, rx.functions.Action and rx.Observer.

Comment: I think the problem is with Jaeger dependencies in your pom. Did you try with above pom dependencies? I've updated my answer.

Comment: Just did and the app works, but no tracer is reported to Jeager. Commited the sample app here: https://github.com/julianocosta89/rxjava-jeager

Comment: I wonder if it will work by itself. Open-tracing provides decorators for Rxjava, maybe you need to use decorators. See my forked version which works fine - https://github.com/akashsolanki/rxjava-jeager.

Comment: Worth reading this - https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-rxjava/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I saw this one, but for all the Spring Cloud samples, I didn't need to instrument anything. All was done automatically, that's why I was expecting the same behavior for RxJava. Instrumenting all the Rx objects work, but that's a manual task, and different from all the others. Also, in your fork you had to add the @Bean, what I wasn't expecting the need as well.

Comment: It's time to raise an issue then - https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-spring-cloud/issues/304